# How to create a modal window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# and WPF. I want to open a new window and remain totally in that window locking the parent i.e. something similar to MessageBox

I have a menu item that I choose calls a method OnClose, I then create and show my confirm close window. I disable the parent but it runs through the entire method I want to wait until the second windows I created has closed.

```
    void OnClose(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        //this.IsEnabled = true;
        ConfirmClose cc = new ConfirmClose();
        this.IsEnabled = false;
        cc.Show();
        cc.Focus();
 // How can I wait here until the windows cc has closed
        this.IsEnabled = true;


    }
```

Comment: I think you might be interested in the OnClosing event, which allows you to cancel the Close

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `.Show()` use [`.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx), then the user can't return to the parent window unless he close the form, like this:

```
 ConfirmClose cc = new ConfirmClose();
 cc.ShowDialog();
```

Assuming that `ConfirmClose` is a `System.Windows`.

Comment: Specifically, he's looking for a _blocking call_.

Comment: @SLaks, he's looking for a *blocking call*, in order to lock the parent window from the user until he close the `ConfirmClose()`, and this what `ShowDialog()` do. This what I understood from the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that is exactly want I wanted.

Comment: @MGA: Yes.  Your answer is completely correct, except that it was missing the correct term.